# Can CloudFront redirect issuing 302?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have setup an S3 redirect to a different domain, but it does a 301 which is going to mess me up later when I need to change that. Using a 302 at least gives me the ability to change it later. Is there a way to do this on CloudFront or get S3 to do it?

Comment: `Domain -> CloudFront -> S3 -> Redirect to new URL` Is that your flow?

Comment: That is my current flow for some domains, but knowing S3 sends 301 means I will have a problem in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use for Lambda@Edge.

You can reference the AWS example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-http-redirect), but at a high level you’re going to create a Lambda function and then add that to your CloudFront distribution as the viewer-request Lambda, which will return the 302 redirect to your user for you; for the redirect you can use the example code and simply update the location value to your value and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check that out now and see how it works!

Comment: No worries. We use the same in production right now, it works beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

FYI - There is now a new cloudfront function which actually runs at edge.

This will redirect to a new domain

```
function handler(event) {
  return {
    statusCode: 302,
    statusDescription: 'Redirect',
    headers:
      { "location": 
        { "value": "<your new domain>" } 
      }
  }
}
```